# Which button should I click?

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am trying to crawl a website which loads pages if i click "Show more products". I am using perl mechanize. Here is the content I got from the website. What should I specify in click_button() so that the Show more product button is clicked?

```
  <div id='lPage' style='display:none' class='lpge'>1</div>
  <div class='clearfix'>
    <div id='divMoreProducts' onclick='javascript:showMoreProductsAjax("All Products")' class='showMoreProd' style='display:none;'>
      <span>Show more products</span>
    </div>
    <div id='divMoreProductsLoader' style='display:none;text-align:center'>
      <img src='http://img2.babyoye.com/skin/frontend/default/babyoye_2012/images/ajax-more-loader.gif'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='botControl'>
    <span style='float:right'><strong>Search result </strong>133</span>
  </div>
</article>
<div id='lPage' style='display:none' class='lpge'>1</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var enable_show_more_product = true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    try {
      jQuery("pre.loadme").lazyLoad();
    } catch(e) {
    }
  });
  jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".showMoreProd").mousedown(function (){
      jQuery(this).addClass("showMoreProdImp");
    }).mouseup(function () {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("showMoreProdImp");
    });
  });
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's much easy to **check actual HTTP request made after clicking this button** in your browser and just *repeat such request in your code* using:

```
$mech->post( URL, Content => {...} );
```

I'm using Firefox's [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) extension for such things...

Answer (score 1):

WWW::Mechanize, as the user manual states, is not Javascript enabled. You're trying to click on a button that will trigger an Ajax request, so you won't get any results by "clicking" on it from WWW::Mechanize.

In cases like this, you need to analyze the whole thing first, trying to understand what kind of request the Ajax call is actually doing. The easiest way to do it is to use a browser that allows you to check individual requests. Personally, I love the way Google Chrome does it:

1. Open the page in Chrome
2. Press Ctrl - Shift - I to open the developer panel
3. Click on the "Network" tab in the panel and click on the "XHR" button on the bottom of the pannel.

Now, everytime you click on a button that makes an Ajax request, you will see a list of each request on the left. If you click on any of them, you are able to see the exact request (headers, form fields, request, response, times, etc).

Not everything you see in there needs to be setup. Generally, you just need to find the form field containing a command that triggers the Ajax-type response from the server. The rest is generally cookies and other stuff the www::Mechanize already handles for you.

Also, don't forget to call `$mech->back()` after everytime you post an Ajax request, so all of your current form fields go back to the state of the page that hosts those buttons.

HTH :-)

Francisco

Comment: (Request-Line) POST /api/ajaxList.php?storeid=1&lazyloader=1&cat=48&cName=QmFieSBEaWFwZXJz&offer_special=0&crsl=0&example=0&p=2&dir=asc&order=popular HTTP/1.1
Host www.example.com
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:20.0; WUID=d007a10bb4a33e7e7ce0d628dc0e22e0; WTB=2937) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Accept */*
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://www.example.com/xyz.html
Content-Length 151
Connection keep-alive
Pragma no-cache